# Luis Dashboard api calls

Tags: api, dashboard, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I'm developing an app to create conversations outside of luis portal. This means that most of the info I get related to my luis app comes from api calls.
The issue I have is that I can't find the api calls to get information from the [Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-use-dashboard)

I know i can get raw information from other api calls, digested and then display it in charts graphs, etc. However some of the api calls have to much payload.

## The reason I want api calls to the dashboard is to retrieve all the data already digested. Any place I can find this api calls?

- A small list of things I want to retrieve is:

  1. Overall predictions.
  2. Predictions per intent.
  3. Intent with prediction errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "official" method provided in the APIs, but if you look at the `Network` tab of the Developer tools of your navigator, you can see several calls done when loading the dashboard page.

One of them is:

```
GET https://LUIS_REGION.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/webapi/v2.0/apps/APP_ID/versions/APP_VERSION/statsmetadata
```

You need to add your `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` in the request headers.

Result:

[image: Stats]

It looks like you have what you are looking for in this call

Comment: Is Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key = Authoring- key ?

Comment: Yes you can use it.